# Error Visual Basic 6 con COM+ y MS DTC

Tags: vb6, microsoft, com

**Editado (26-5-21)**: He encontrado estos links al respecto, pero no me convencen mucho en la solución. :(

https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/troubleshoot/windows/win32/cannot-start-transaction-ms-dtc

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/c03838d4-d2f3-4c35-8acb-463ed74996ea/com-vb6-application-on-64-bit-system-abortduetoconnectiondownfromrm-error?forum=netfxbcl

https://www.ibm.com/mysupport/s/question/0D50z000060GHAK/com-application-on-64-bit-error-occurred-during-transaction-or-heuristic-processing-reason-code-16-subcode-38004d00e?language=es En este caso, habla de VB6 64bits; pero el que utilizo es de 32bits

---

Tras ejecutar VB6, ha saltado este error de sistema, con COM+ y Microsoft Distributed Transation Coordinator.

Por el momento, me han dicho que hay que parar ciertos servicios del portátil en el Administrador de tareas (HP, Lenovo, Asus, Toshiba...), pero no he encontrado una solución factible.

Cómo lo resuelvo, por favor?

Muchas gracias de antemano! :)

[image: Error Visual Basic 6]

Comment: Este tipo de errores generalmente registran información adicional en el EventLog de windows. Revísalo porque una causa puede ser que MS DTC no está arrancando.

Comment: @PabloGutiérrez Entiendo, pero soy principiante en estos temas de VB, y cómo se relacionan con los registros de Windows (egedit). Hay alguno de ellos que tengo que cambiar su valor o generar uno nuevo? :/

Comment: No me refería al Regedit. EventLog hace referencia al lugar donde windows hace un registro (Log) de los eventos del sistema. Busca en windows "Visor de eventos" o ejecuta el comando `eventvwr.msc` en Inicio > Ejecutar.

Comment: Está bien, iré revisando por EventLog. Muchas gracias! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He encontrado la solución poniendo todo a 1 los registros asociados a MS DTC. Una vez hecho, reinicias el portátil y ejecutas el VB6 con total normalidad. :)

[image: Poner todo a 1 Registro MS DTC]